# Screenshot region between two images and multiple monitors

Tags: pyautogui

I am trying to take a screenshot using multiple monitors and having no luck.  Code below

```
import pyautogui

f_cast = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('wsb-For.png',  confidence="0.85")
end_cast = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('wsb-end.png',  confidence="0.85")
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot(region = (f_cast,end_cast))
screenshot.save("screen.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from PIL import ImageGrab
from functools import partial
ImageGrab.grab = partial(ImageGrab.grab, all_screens=True)

import pyautogui

f_cast = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('wsb-For.png',  confidence="0.85")
end_cast = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('wsb-end.png',  confidence="0.85")
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
screenshot.save("screen.png")
```

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/99fer7/comment/e4neq6p/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. Also see [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/62576) for more information.

Comment: This gives me a screen shot of all my monitors and not a region between two images.